# Need help trying to switch frames

Tags: python, selenium

The frame I'm  trying to switch to when looping back through my program changes after the first loop and then I'm not able to access it and the second loop fails. The frame name changes by a factor of 3 every time, here is an example of what I did to switch frames originally:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-1']/iframe"))

Next frame

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-4']/iframe"))

Next frame

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-7']/iframe"))
```

How would I add another 3 to each frame so I end up in the right frame after the first loop?

Here is the element(I changed the SRC because of how long it was):

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="/website/impactingActivities.do.dialogId=ui-id-1" onload="top.hideLoadingDiv('ui-id-1','ui-id-1');top.rightclickdisable('ui-id-1')" style="visibility: visible;"></iframe>
```

```py
def AccountSearch():

    def get_iframe_id(multiplier):
        delta = 3
        return str(1 + delta * multiplier)

    mult = 0

    start = time.time()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmLeftNavSearch")

    searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchParam")

    MyAccountNumber = (AccountEntry.get())

    searchbar.send_keys(MyAccountNumber)

    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    newsearchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchParam")

    newsearchbar.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmSearchResults")


    searchresults = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bodytextlink").click()


    print("***************************** Impacting Balance ********************************")


    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmContent")

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    Activity = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu23']")).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ActImpct = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu266']")).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    ClickImpct = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu266']").click()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    #start of for or where loop

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))


    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5)
        Row3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tblDetails']/tbody/tr[3]")))
        print("ACTIVITY IMPACTING BALANCE, REVIEW NEEDED")
        print("\n")
    except:
        print("No Activity Impacting Balance")
        print("\n")


    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tblButtonBar2']/input").click()

        #Return to Summary

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmContent")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu4']").click()


    print("***************************** Port Management *****************************")

    print("\n")

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmContent")
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmPage")

    PortManagement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tblData']/tbody/tr[1]/th[4]/a").click()


    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    mult += 1
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))


    try:
        CashEquiv = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//*[contains(text(), 'Equivalent')]//following::td[4]")
        print("Cash Equivalent:", CashEquiv.text)
        print("\n")
    except:
        print("No Cash Equivalents")
        print("\n")

    try:
        USdollar = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr//*[contains(text(), 'US Dollar')]//following::td[4]")).text
        print("US Dollar Amount:", USdollar.replace("\n", ' '))
        print("\n")
    except:
        print("Error, review US Dollar manually")
        print("\n")

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tblDialogButtonBar']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input").click()


    print("***************************** Transaction Inquiry ******************************")

    print("\n")

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to.frame("ifrmContent")

    action = ActionChains(driver)
    Activity = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu23']")).perform()
    TrnsInq = action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu40']")).perform()
    ClickTrnsInq = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divMenu40']").click()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    mult += 1
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))


    try:
        ClosingFee = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//*[contains(text(), 'Closing')]//following::td[5]")

        print("Closing Fee:", ClosingFee.text)

        print("\n")

    except:
        print("Closing Fee: ** No Closing Fee Charged **")
        print("\n")


    CloseTransactionInquiry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tblDialogButtonBar']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input").click()

    end = time.time()

    totaltime = end - start
    print("Time Elapsed:", totaltime)


SearchButton = Button(window, text="Search", command=AccountSearch)
SearchButton.grid(column=1, row=8)
SearchButton.configure(background = "light grey")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the html for the frame? In general I would suggest using a selector that won't change, is there some other way to identify the `iframe`?

Comment: @mrfreester Unfortunately it doesn't have a very good choice for selectors. Xpath changes, it doesn't have a name, doesn't have an ID. I was using a partial SRC to get it before but that didn't work for this case.

Comment: You could do something tricky to pass along a variable that increases and is used in a dynamic xpath that multiplies by 3 each time... but that should be an absolute last resort from a maintenance perspective. If you can post the html for the `iframe` and maybe a couple of it's parent elements in the hierarchy I might be able to make some selector suggestions.

Comment: @mrfreester posted the HTML. I feel like I may be in that last resort territory. I really do think I'll have to do something like you suggested, wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to grab anything else. It's basically a pop up window, also tried to switch to it using the ```switch_to.alert``` command in Selenium but it doesn't recognize it as that either.

Comment: Could you try `//iframe[contains(@src, 'impactingActivities.do.dialogId=ui-id')]` There might be something more appropriate to use in one of the parent elements, but let me know if that works.

Comment: No such luck on that one either. It'll still find the original frame with using that code, I think it has to add another 3 to the ID.

Comment: I think I misunderstood, so all these frames exist on the page at the same time? I was under the impression that it was the same frame but the `id` kept changing. I think I can give a general example of looping to handle this, but this sounds like it might be veering into the category of being a test that is too _clever_. But those can be worth it at times :) I'll update with an attempt at an answer

Comment: I see that you have posted a lot of code, most of which has nothing to do with your question. Can you reduce your code example to illustrate what you are trying to do? No more and no less. Read [mcve] for some tips on making a good code example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on looping through all of the `iframes` I would grab all of those elements first with a more general selector, and then use a `for` each loop.

```
# grab all of your iframes at once if you have access to them
iframeElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'ui-id']/iframe")

for iframe in iframeElements:
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

A potential approach for when they are not all obtainable at first as mentioned in the comments, you could keep track of the delta, which is always 3, and the multiplier, which increases by 1 each time. :

```
# outside of loop
def get_iframe_id(multiplier):
    delta = 3
    return str(1 + delta * multiplier)

mult = 0

#start of for or where loop
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))

    # Next frame
    mult += 1
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))

    # Next frame
    mult +=1
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id = 'ui-id-" + get_iframe_id(mult) + "']/iframe"))

    mult += 1

    # Whatever you do to check for breaking out of loop
# End of loop
```

Here is the math spelled out for what's going on with the multiplier increasing by 1 each time:

```
id = 1 + delta * multiplier
1 = 1 + 3 * 0
4 = 1 + 3 * 1
7 = 1 + 3 * 2
10 = 1 + 3 * 3
13 = 1 + 3 * 4
16 = 1 + 3 * 5
etc...
```

Comment: Note, this will not work if all your `iframes` aren't visible on the page right away... Let me know if that's the case and I may be able to provide an update for that with some more information.

Comment: They are not all visible on the page at once. I think this is tricky to explain, but basically it runs through the program the first time and opens 3 what I'd call pop-up pages on this ajax website. So lets say it made 3 new frames, 1, 3, 7. So once it runs through the program once, the next frame it opens should be 10. But if it's looping back through the program it won't be able to go to 10, because for some reason, even though it's not visible to me, it will still find frame 1 and switch to that. I hope I explained that well.

Comment: I think I understand now... so this is a loop where there are 3 frames visible each time. At first it is 1, 3, and 7. The second time through the loop it would be 10, 13, 16? Do they always come in 3 at a time? How do you know when there are no more frames to loop through (IE. Exit criteria for the loop)

Comment: Correct it would be 10, 13, 16. I don't really have a clue as to why they are numbered this way and not 1, 2, 3...etc. Once the program gets all the data from the desired pages/windows I've had it navigate to, it returns to the home page of the website and waits for the user to input another account number. Once another account number is put in they would press 'Search' in the tkinter window and it will run through the loop again except using that new account number.

Comment: I added the general math for the loop. I get the feeling with Ajax you may run into issues with waiting for objects to appear, but I think that general logic should help get to the next step.

Comment: Got a ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str```

This error occurs on the ```driver.switch_to.frame``` line

Comment: oops, sorry I don't use python often... I edited my answer. Basically `get_iframe_id` returns string instead of int

Comment: Good news, bad news. Adding the +3 to every frame on the first loop did work. However on the second loop it couldn't successfully do it. Is there a way you could suggest ending the loop so the last +3 would work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197306/discussion-between-mrfreester-and-loons22).